# How to log a map/struct in elixir

Tags: elixir

How do you log a map/struct type in ELixir without having to implement `protocol String.Chars`?

```
require Logger
Logger.debug  %{my: "map"}
** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol String.Chars not implemented for %{my: "map"}
    (elixir) lib/string/chars.ex:3: String.Chars.impl_for!/1
    (elixir) lib/string/chars.ex:17: String.Chars.to_string/1
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `inspect/2` - https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#inspect/2

It parses the data structure into an algebra document which can be printed with the logger.

```
iex(4)> Logger.debug inspect(%{a: 1})
08:47:32.776 [debug] %{a: 1}
:ok
```

Comment: I thought inspect seemed logical, but had been using IO.inspect!  Just for clarification, it's Kernel.inspect

Comment: The link shown above is to IO.inspect. The actual link to Kernel.inspect/2 is here - http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#inspect/2

Answer (score 5):

The Elixir way of writing [arathunku's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35009043) would be using the pipe syntax:

```
iex(3)> %{a: 1} |> inspect() |> Logger.debug()

23:20:30.265 [debug] %{a: 1}
:ok
```